# Insert a "-" after third character for whole column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column (Name is the header of the column) with 8 character numbers. I am looking for a query to insert a '-' after the third character of every row of data.

For example if I have:

```
|   Name   |
|----------|
| 99912345 |
```

I want to get:

```
|   Name    |
|-----------|
| 999-12345 |
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT INSERT(name, 3, 0, "-");
```

The database I am using is called temp.Test1 on mySQL

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I've added it thanks

Comment: @Starbucks, he means to tag wether you're using mysql, postgres, mssql etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, use `substring` to divide your value and `concat` to put it back together.

```sql
set @test = 99912345; 

select concat(
  substring(@test, 1, 3),
  '-',
  substring(@test, 4)
);
```

gives `999-12345`

---

Edit: You can also make a virtual column which does this for you, and just retrieve the column in your application.

```sql
alter table `test1`
add `formattedName` varchar(9) as (
  concat(
    substring(`name`, 1, 3),
    '-',
    substring(`name`, 4)
  )
);
```

```
select `formattedName` from `test`
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9fc2caeb8439d4c88ca5fd2eeccc83e)

Comment: You're welcome. See my updated answer for a better solution using a virtual column ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You were close:

```
SELECT INSERT(name, 4, 0, '-') from mytable
```

Here is the demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=430748c6d517a8099035b108e0be0729)

Comment: I am very interested in why is this not selected as a correct answer ? Thanks @Starbucks ofr the answer.

Comment: It did work but for my instance I wanted to avoid the insert statement (my fault for not mentioning) so I used the sub string function and then concated it back together. Thank you though!

Comment: Ok, I know it works....Thanks again for the explanation...